# PHP str_replace regex to remove link with tags

Tags: php

How would I use str_replace to remove this following link and tags all together.

Tags needs to be removed, ignoring link and link text all together:

```
<p><a href=""></a></p>
```

Also, this one:

```
<p><em><a href=""></a></em></p>
```

Note, I don't need to grab any content from this tags, simply remove them from my data. Thanks.

Comment: I've found solution for "<p><a href=""></a></p>"

    $match = preg_replace('/<p><a[^>][^>]*>(.*)<\/a><\/p>/isU', '', $match);

Now need to figure out one more which is "<p><em><a href=""></a></em></p>", which should not be that hard now that I have that top regex :)

Comment: I found the solution my self, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or some substitute.

Also, please read [the accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

**Edit**

Also, as Ed Marty pointed out there is the [strip_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and I guess I'll point to [filter_var](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php).

Comment: [`DOMNode::removeChild`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php).  You might find an answer that will hack your HTML to do what you need right now.  But, no correct answer to parsing HTML should ever involve regex or `str*` functions.

Comment: I need to use str_replace function or preg_replace, no exceptions. But thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you enslaved to `str_replace` or `preg_replace`?  These are well documented as very poor HTML parsers.  Your question has actually sparked a desire to write a blog post wanting to know why developers do this.  I see this question all the time and all the time the answer comes back "Use HTML parser".  Why not listen to that answer?

Comment: The reason is for custom rss parser to remove unwanted links ;) I try to stay away from HTML parsers, I code my own ;)

Comment: @Charles Sprayberry I will agree that `DOM` manipulation is certainly ideal for manipulating html/xml, but it is incredibly slow even when compared to PCRE.  If you aren't concerned with nested tags, PCRE is going to be simpler and faster.  It is also a bit difficult to remove elements with php native DOM parsers, especially when compared to its other string manipulation functions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function instead.

Comment: Again, not what I need. I need to just remove those following tags not all of them :)